# How can I know the last child of a level according to a path index in a list

Tags: algorithm, sqlite, kotlin, nested-lists

I have a nested table with many levels of parent and child elements. It returns me the levels of each record and the path index as follow:

[image]

How can I make other field that says if the row is the last row child of the path_index parent? I've included here a manual example from sql here, **with my current query**: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=3963054e14723bd7dae146ab82ae936c

Basically is something like that: inside path_index 1.1 has 1.1.1, 1.1.2 and 1.1.3, the row with 1.1.3 will be the last row of parent 1.1, but inside 1.1.2 has 1.1.2.1, then 1.1.2.1 is true because is the last child of 1.1.2, then it receives true as last row parent, a complete example follows:

[image]

How can I do an algorithm for that? It can be done with SQL or with Java/Kotlin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the column `rn` from `cte` to check with window function `MAX()` if it is the last child of each parent:

```
WITH 
  levels AS (
    SELECT *, 0 lvl FROM items
    UNION ALL
    SELECT i.*, l.lvl + 1 
    FROM items i INNER JOIN levels l
    ON l.id = i.parentId 
  ),
  row_numbers AS (
    SELECT id, item_name, parentId, MAX(lvl) lvl,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY parentId, lvl ORDER BY id) rn
    FROM levels
    GROUP BY id, item_name, parentId
  ),
  cte AS (
    SELECT id, item_name, parentId, lvl, rn, rn || '' path_index
    FROM row_numbers
    UNION ALL
    SELECT r.id, r.item_name, r.parentId, r.lvl, r.rn,
           c.path_index || '.' || r.rn
    FROM row_numbers r INNER JOIN cte c
    ON r.parentId = c.id 
  )
SELECT id, item_name, parentId, lvl, path_index,
       rn = MAX(rn) OVER (PARTITION BY parentId) lastRowFromParent 
FROM cte  
GROUP BY id
HAVING MAX(LENGTH(path_index))
ORDER BY path_index + 0, path_index
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=075c4b8c09d32e7a80ac4e2e83c41f74).